# IBeam caret on contextmenu of RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I create a contextmenu and add this to a richtextbox. Now when I Right Click on the richtextbox, the contextmenu appears, but the cursors is an IBeam caret and not the default arrow.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
        var tb = new RichTextBox();
        tb.Text = "test";

        var items = new[] {new MenuItem("Save",SaveTextFile)};
        var ctxMenu = new ContextMenu(items);
        tb.ContextMenu = ctxMenu;
```

Thanks,

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm dreadfully sorry, but there is no way to fix this. It has been an issue with Winforms for a long time. See [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/299045/cursor-is-wrong-when-popup-contextmenu-on-richtextbox) and [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/201741/richtextbox-contextmenu-displays-ibeam-cursor-instead-of-arrow-cursor).

Microsoft promised to look into it, but apparently they haven't fixed it yet.